# Usage of ようとしない

Tags: grammar, syntax

Why <開こうとしない> can't be used in the second option?

Is it so because the cap is inanimate object?

[image: Exemple]

Comment: The lid isn't trying to open, is it?

Comment: I think it would be better to say why you think it COULD be used, so we could correct any underlying misunderstandings. What is your understanding of the おうとする construction?

Comment: @Nothingatall that's right - "no matter how many times I try to open the lid, it remains sealed"

Comment: @Kurausukun found this in my exercise textbook during studies, http://i.imgur.com/PiPD8Lz.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A) このジャムのふたは、いくら開け「よう」としても「開かない」

B) このジャムのふたは、いくら開け「よう」としても「開こうとしない」

C) このジャムのふたは、いくら開け「ろう」としても「開かない」

D) このジャムのふたは、いくら開け「ろう」としても「開こうとしない」

---

First of all, there is no usage as 「開けろう」in Japanese.
The choices C & D are incorrect.

Second, the lid is no human (or even it does not have a life, just a object).
So the lid does not have own consciousness.
「開こうとしない」 means "someone does not want to open". But object does not have own consciousness.
That's why 「開こうとしない」is incorrect.